# Extracting description out of an html page

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, html-content-extraction

I am trying to extract title and description out of web pages, using DOMdocument(), I am successful in extracting title like this

```
$d=new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($html);
$title=$d->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->textContent;
```

I can extract the description by looping through all `meta tags` and checking for the `name="desctiption"`attribute but looping makes the process slow so wanted to know if there can be a direct method for extracting content using some attribute selector in php DOMdocument??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with DOMDocument alone, but it is possible in combination with with DOMXPath:

```
$html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Dom - Xpath test</title>
<meta name="description" content="The first description meta tag" />
<meta name="keywords" content="none, no-keywords" />
<meta name="description" content="the second description tag" />
</head>
<body>
<p>This is the test HTML</p>
</body>
</html>
';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$domx = new DOMXPath($dom);
$desc = $domx->query("//meta[@name='description']");

$i = 0;
while ($item = $desc->item($i++)) {
    echo '<p>'.$item->getAttribute('content').'</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [get_meta_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) function of php.

You can do it like that:

```
$d=new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($html);
$title=$d->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->textContent;
$meta = get_meta_tags($html);
$description = $meta["description"];
```

Comment: this  extracts meta from a file, any idea about how to use it with html strings?